# How to click on a link in selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is My HTML code, Please provide any suggestion to click on the particular link, i have tried with all the alternative but nothing work out.
Please please suggest.

```
<tr>
<td width="170" valign="top" style="word-wrap:break-word; word-break:break-all;">
<div id="ServAndFeature" class="left">
<h2 style="width: 150px;">Services and Features</h2>
<ul class="service">
<input id="BVECheck" type="hidden" value="Metro E EDI" name="BVECheck">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li class="current">
<li>
<b>Equipment Fee</b>
<ul class="firstChild" name="/Equipment Fee Configuration/">
<li>
<a id="uniq_7151[B@2569a1ab" onclick="constructProcessParameter('feature','uniq_7151[B@2569a1ab','uniq_7151[B@2569a1ab','','','Metro E Equipment Fee','2985725')" onmouseover="getToolTip('Equipment Fee','Equipment Fee Configuration','Equipment Fee Configuration','uniq_7151[B@2569a1ab')" href="#">Equipment Fee Configuration</a>
</li>
</ul>
<input id="BVECheck" type="hidden" value="Metro E Equipment Fee" name="BVECheck">
</li>
<li>
<li>
```

I tried the below approach:

```
//img[contains(@title,'Selected Service Order for Edit')]

//a[contains(@href,'UNI:10/100')]/img;
//*[@id='ServAndFeature']/ul/li[2]/ul/li/a
css=    a[href*='Equipment Fee Configuration']
xpath = "//a[text()='Equipment Fee Configuration']"
ul.service li:nth-child(8) ul > li a
//a[starts-with(@id, 'uniq_') and contains(@id, 'B@24d742b9')]
//input[matches(@id, 'uniq_.*B@24d742b9')]
```

Comment: We have 4 link is there in the same page under the same li...., i am trying to click on the 4th link which is there under li[8], but every time it clicking on the li[1] link

Comment: I mean, do any errors detected when you try to click link with your code?

Comment: is there any way i can suggest developer to modify the HTML as per my requirement, please suggest Andersson..

Comment: No i am not getting any error only it finding the wrong link.....

Comment: if there are 4 links on page that are hardly distinguishable try `cssSelector` `ul.service a:nth-of-type(4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of those

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Equipment Fee Configuration')]"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".firstChild > li > a"));
```

Comment: i have tried all the approach, but still the same issue exist, Even i tried to give the absolute xpath, instead of clicking on the 4 hyperlink it clicking on the 1st one.

Comment: /html/body/form/div/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/ul/li[8]/ul/li/a

Answer (score 0):

You can try `driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Your link text here")).Click();`

or

You can get the link text at run time and store it in a string and then use your programming languge to visit the link.

```
string url= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath or CSS selector as instructed").getAttribute("href");
```

and then write a code to visit this

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

That's how you can get the response code as well if you want to assert only the response`